# python serial connection login

Tags: python, serial-port

I am new to Python and trying to connect to a router using serial connection, which means there exists a step of typing in "username/password". Can anyone provide a example of serial connection with username/password being involved in?

Thanks so much!!

Comment: Have you looked at pyserial and its miniterm example?

Comment: @PatrickMaupin Yup! I did some research about Pyserial can not find an example with username/password case ..

Comment: You can give a username and password to miniterm, right?

Comment: In other words, how is username/password different from any other programmed interaction?

Comment: @PatrickMaupin Do you mind giving couple lines of code showing where to add username/password? It does not have to be exactly right but I am just trying to understand the basic idea and concepts. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are asking about the ability to handle requests from the serial port (such as a username or password prompt), and then to respond to those requests appropriately, such as by sending the username or password.

This is a fairly common use-case, but is not handled directly by pyserial, which only handles dumb pipes for bytes in both directions.

One package which might be of use is pexpect.  Here is a paper that describes using pexpect in conjunction with pyserial to control and test routers:

http://wiki.ninux.org/ClauzClauz?action=AttachFile&do=get&target=clauz_router_testing_framework_4_python.pdf

Comment: Thanks so much for your help!